# VBA equivalent of JAXB for writing XML automatically based on class definition

Tags: xml, vba, excel, jaxb

I'm looking for a shortcut for writing the contents of ANY vba object (i.e. instance of a vba class) to XML. I am aware that I can write code to manually do this per class (creating nodes and values etc via MSXML2.DOMDocument objects). However, I'm accustomed to having libraries at my disposal (e.g. JAXB for Java) that can inspect the class at runtime and write the object to XML automatically, without any code being written that is specific to the structure of the class for which it is creating xml from objects.

I've tried to find a vba library that does something like this but can't find anything. Does anyone have any suggestions that DON'T involve writing code to write xml for every single class I want to build xml for?

The background to this is storing arbitrarily structured data from existing MS Excel applications to xml, to be picked up by other applications (written in Java, Python).

Thanks.

Comment: VBA doesn't support reflection. Short of parsing the VBA code yourself, which by default is precluded by security settings, you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I am steadily discovering that VBA is everything I hate and nothing I like